# How can I return html code by using `render_to_response`?

Tags: python, decorator, render-to-response

my return code is:

```
return render_to_response(
        'login.html',
        context_instance=RequestContext(request, locals())
    )
```

and it sometimes works as follows :
[image]

but sometimes when I use it in decorator, it becomes
this and it doesn't work :

[image]

I want to know what happened... and how can I get html code...

Comment: when I ues it in decorator = "when I use it in decorator"

Answer (score 0):

### Got the reason.

In the first scene，the request is from browser directly. But in the second scene, it's from JS. Just like JS sends request_a, and request_a's response is redirect to request_b, when JS got the response from request_b, it just think it's a normal response, JS could not parse it by html and show. So, if the same request_a is send by browser, it works, but when send from JS, it doesn't. It doesn't matter with decorator. I'm sorry to ask with wrong direction.